# UIWebView strange scrolling behaviour within tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, scroll

I have a problem with my UIWebViews - they scrolls only if I touch and drag their content within small area (I filled it with yellow. Red area is the area which doesn't response to my touches when I'm about to scroll the webview.

Here you can see my tableview with two custom cells, each contains it's own UIWebView with text and image:

[image]

I'd like my webview to response to my touches within their actual bounds. But it doesn't.

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add webview as subview to cell's content view?

Comment: That appears to be a 44 height area. (default cell height). Where do you change the height? Just a thought.

Comment: @PearlWhite yes indeed

Comment: @MarkM you were right, i've changed content view height and now all works fine! Post the answer and get your cookie : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the content view height from 44 (the default value) to the height you are using.